# Bash variable assignment explanation {var:=0} {var:-0}?

Tags: bash

I'm a bash amateur reading up books and manuals for learning further. I came across following script in a book that calculates total size and shows the use of command substitution. I could not understand the parts that contain **`{totalsize:=0}`**, **`{size:-0}`**, **`{totalsize-unset}`**. Could somebody please explain?

At first sight, it looked like an array but what do the operators `:=` and `:-` do here and `totalsize` was the variable containing the values but when I `echo ${totalsize-unset}`, it does return the sum of filesizes in PWD. Is `-unset` some kind of built-in ?

```
$ while read perms links owner group size month day time file
> do
>  printf "%10d %s\n" "$size" "$file"
>  totalsize=$(( ${totalsize:=0} + ${size:-0} ))
> done < <(ls -l *)
$ echo ${totalsize-unset}
```

Comment: No offense, but if the books and manuals you read teach you to parse the output of `ls`, you'd better: (1) throw them away right now and try to forget all the bad stuff they taught you; (2) write to their authors and complain that it's a pity they teach so bad and broken techniques, and ask for a refund. Really, do it.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf (http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7146986-pro-bash-programming) I'll throw it once I'm done. I'd also like to read the book that turned you into an almost perfect snob. Cheers!

Comment: What page is that script on in the book?

Comment: I'm not a perfect snob. Look, seriously, your command is very dangerous as it allows for arbitrary code to be executed. For example, a file name containing a newline, with, after the newline character a fifth field of the form `a[$(...)]` where `...` is any command, then this command will be executed. Don't believe me? do this in your directory: `touch $'\n_ _ _ _ a[$(echo>gniourf\ \'hello\ Donbhupi\')]'`. It will create a file with a weird name. Whatever. Then run your command. You'll see that you'll have a new file, called `gniourf` that contains a message for you.

Comment: As @gniourf_gniourf says, parsing `ls` is generally considered bad form.  Some of the reasons why are discussed [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I hope you understand that your command is broken, and can lead to arbitrary code execution. It's very dangerous. Time for you to forget about the bad methods you learned so far. Really.

Comment: @RobKielty page 38/217

Comment: If I could, I would rename this book into _Broken Bash Programming_. Seriously, ask for a refund.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation@gniourf_gniourf , I understand now that parsing ls could do things I don't want to happen. Could you guys still shed some light on the data-structure/operation that I asked this question for?

Comment: Still more discussion of the issue: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: It seems you need some solid material. How about the official reference (it's not perfect, but at least it's the official documentation). You'll find the explanation of this in the [Parameter Expansion section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion). You're lucky it's one of the first expansions they mention. `:)`.

Comment: Here it's the conjunction of three things that made arbitrary code execution possible: parsing of `ls` (and we can forge some cool filenames if we're creative enough), with the use of `read` _without_ the `-r` switch (I was happy to put as many spaces I liked, appropriately backslashed!), together with the raw use of one of the fields in arithmetic context! Really bad coding practice here!!!

Comment: Thanks guys, I should have been able to find this manual had i lurked moar. Thanks for your explanation and references! I'll ditch the book.

Comment: I guess I need reputation of some sort to vote up your useful comments but this being my first question here, I lack any. Thanks though!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf So I was reading the GNU bash manual from the link you gave and it also has examples that parse output of `ls`. [GNU-Parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#GNU-Parallel)

Comment: @Donbhupi: that's why I mentioned it's not perfect in my previous comment. A good source of information is the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), made by the most knowledgeable folks I know of. [Parsing `ls` is detailed here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf thanks a ton for your inputs on this. I'd like to believe it's made me somewhat less stupid. I was trying to analyze the special filename you made me `touch': `\n` sends the parser off to next line and then five spaces in the name shift it to be read as `size` and what's remaining is invalid to be printed as a digit but what makes this be executed as a command? Is that an array script of some sort if passed as an integer to an arithmetic addition?
And yes @John1024 provided that link about parsing `ls` in his first comment.

Comment: btw @gniourf_gniourf if I were to parse `ls` on linux system files, that should never be dangerous I assume, eg.: `( zcat $( ls -tr /var/log/apt/history.log*.gz ) ; cat /var/log/apt/history.log ) | egrep '^Commandline:'` to see what apps were manually installed on a debian as there's no easier/shorter way to do this in bash or perl/python.

Comment: What makes the command executable is that, in arithmetic context, Bash tries to derefence as much as possible. For example: `a=b b=c c=42; echo $((a))` will output `42`. For fun, you may try `a=b b=a; echo $((a))` or even `a=a; echo $((a))`. Now with arrays: `a=(); b='a[$(ls)]'; echo "b=$b"; echo "\$((b))=$((b))"`. This executes `ls`. That because Bash needs to know which key you're using, so it's trying to derefence it... but for this it executes the `$(ls)`.

Comment: Regarding your command `zcat $( ls -tr /var/log/apt/history.log*.gz )`: it's probably fine since the log files have controlled names. In this case, the problem isn't about arbitrary code execution. It's only about pathname expansion and word splitting: it would only break the command. But since you're pretty sure that the files have controlled names, it's fine. Though, you could enforce checking like so: `( shopt -s extglob failglob; zcat $(ls -tr /var/log/apt/history.log+([[:digit:]]).gz ) ; cat /var/log/apt/history.log ) | egrep '^Commandline:'`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf took me a good while to understand the arithmetic tweak but it sure is fun and intriguing and maybe the best thing I've learned so far on SO. Thanks for the shopt part too. You are a pro sir, I would take my hat off if I wore one. Wish you had a website, blog or a book!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Ok let's be fair it's a contrived example to demonstrate Process Substitution with no warning about the security risks highlighted here. Unfortunate.)

In Bash, variables can be manipulated or expanded according to the syntax described here :

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#PARAMSUBREF

The intention in the above script is simply to assign zero to totalsize if it does not have a value. totalsize will not have a value during the first iteration of the loop. zero will be used in the calculation instead.

There are a miriad of ways of achieving the same result. It would make more sense to use the `du -h` command.

Run `man du` first and understand what this command does (It estimates files space usage)